# Shared Preferences for Activity?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have 3 activities

1. main
2. setting
3. Emergency for others

and I have saved the shared preferences in setting .but the problem is that when I click on save button it save it and go back to main activity .there is a exit button in main activity .when I click on it .it goes back to setting activity instead of closing the application.

this is the code for **setting activity**:

```
@SuppressLint("ShowToast")   
public class Setting extends Activity {

TextView name ;
TextView mobile;

public static final String Blood = "BloodDonor";
public static final String Name = "namekey";
public static final String Mobile="mobileKey";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

     name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     mobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

     sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Blood, MODE_PRIVATE);
         if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name))
         {
             name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, null));

         }
         if (sharedpreferences.contains(Mobile))
         {
            mobile.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Mobile, null));
         } 


}

    public void run (View view)
    {
        String n = name.getText().toString();
        String m = mobile.getText().toString();
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Name, n);
        editor.putString(Mobile, m);

        editor.commit();
    }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.setting, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

this is the code for **main activity:**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSetting);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Setting.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Button btnExit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnexit);
    btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
             System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    Button btnEmerForOthers=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEmerForOthers);
    btnEmerForOthers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EmergencyForOthers.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: What is that you want???

Comment: i want to save the data in preferences and then close the app .and when i start the app . the preferences should be there in setting activity.

Comment: but I can not see where you are using SharedPreferences in your code

Comment: You have to call `super.onDestroy();` after `android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);` for closing the application

Comment: i have updated the code of setting ... pls check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `finish()` in `Main` `Activity`:

```
btnExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
    }
});
```